# Timer isn't dealing with seconds properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I change the minutes on the timer it works perfectly, but when I change the seconds on the timer, no matter what, it instantly stops. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This program is apart of a codepen exercise. When I had the timer on a countdown setting it worked perfectly, but when I changed it to countup it stopped working for the seconds.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', documentLoaded, false);

var startTime;
var limit;
var timer;

function documentLoaded() {
  "use strict";

  var timerElement = document.getElementById("timer");
  timerElement.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      startTimer();
      timerElement.blur();
    }
  });
}

function startTimer() {
  startTime = new Date();
  limit = parseInt(document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML);

  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
}

function updateTime() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var elapsed = (currentTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;

  var minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

  var totalSeconds = minutes * 60 + seconds;
  if (totalSeconds >= limit * 60) {
    document.getElementById("timer").classList.add("red");
    clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timer").classList.remove("red");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#timer-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0781D4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#timer {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ejercio No. 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="timer-container">
    <div id="timer" contenteditable="true">00:00</div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set the limit correctly - you set it directly to the content of the timer, which includes non numeric characters such as ":". When using `parseInt` on something that isn't all digits, anything after the first non numeric character is discarded. Therefore, by using anything under a minute to test with, limit will be set to 0, as "00:30" would result in 0 from `parseInt`, as only text from before the colon is used. To fix this, split the text at the colon and convert the minutes into seconds, as shown in the snippet

```js
let time = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML.split(":");
//if time = "01:30", limit = 1 + 30/60 = 1.5 minutes
limit = parseInt(time[0]) + parseInt(time[1])/60;
```

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', documentLoaded, false);

var startTime;
var limit;
var timer;

function documentLoaded() {
  "use strict";

  var timerElement = document.getElementById("timer");
  timerElement.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      startTimer();
      timerElement.blur();
    }
  });
}

function startTimer() {
  startTime = new Date();
  let time = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML.split(":");
  limit = parseInt(time[0]) + parseInt(time[1])/60;

  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
}

function updateTime() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var elapsed = (currentTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;

  var minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

  var totalSeconds = minutes * 60 + seconds;
  if (totalSeconds >= limit * 60) {
    document.getElementById("timer").classList.add("red");
    clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timer").classList.remove("red");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#timer-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0781D4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#timer {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ejercio No. 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="timer-container">
    <div id="timer" contenteditable="true">00:00</div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: idk how i didn't notice that, thank you.